# How to read objects (Polymorphic) of the chosen class, from the XML using JAX-B

Tags: java, list, jaxb, polymorphism

I created a list of polymorphic objects. I can convert them into XML and vice versa (marshall and unmarshal using JAXB.) But I would like to read only the objects from the chosen class.

I used a few tutorials about converting object lists by JAXB, for example this one:
http://memorynotfound.com/convert-xml-to-polymorphic-object-using-jax-b/ or this one: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
I have got Animal list, and two classes that extends the abstract animal class, Dog, Cat and a Bird. I saved that list(Containing dogs and cats) to XML, and I would like to get from the XML file only the Cats. Is it possible to make?

Using the code from the tutorial -> http://memorynotfound.com/convert-xml-to-polymorphic-object-using-jax-b/

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    Root root = (Root)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

I would get ouptut:

> Root{animals=[com.memorynotfound.xml.jaxb.Dog@520a3426, com.memorynotfound.xml.jaxb.Cat@18eed359,com.memorynotfound.xml.jaxb.Bird@643bd123]}

What i Try to achieve is:

> Root{animals=[ com.memorynotfound.xml.jaxb.Cat@18eed359]}

In one of the answers i got an idea of XMLEvent. It is a very fine idea, but almost every tutorial says about filtering. What I want to achieve is to get rid of all the other classes.
I tried to change the code:

```
public XMLEvent nextEvent() throws XMLStreamException {
    // Read next event
    XMLEvent e = super.nextEvent();
    // If it's a start element for dog
    if (e.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&  ("Cat".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()) ||
            "Bird".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()))
    )
    {

        // Then run through events until a closing dog event
        do {
            e = super.nextEvent();
        } while (e.getEventType() != XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT || ! ("Cat".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()) ||
                "Bird".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()))

        );
        // then read next event after the  ends
        e = super.nextEvent();
    }
    return e;
}
```

But it is not working, so I am not sure if I understand the solution.

Comment: I think you have issues with boolean operators precedence. I've updated the solution to support multiple filtered values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader` and filter some events. Here is a silly - but working - example:

```
public final class FilteredXmlEventReader extends EventReaderDelegate {

    final Set<String> filteredElements;

    FilteredXmlEventReader(XMLEventReader delegate, String... filteredElements) {
        super(delegate);
        this.filteredElements = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(filteredElements));
    }

    public XMLEvent nextEvent() throws XMLStreamException {
        // Read next event

        XMLEvent e = super.nextEvent();
        // If it's a start element for any filtered
        if (e.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && filteredElements.contains(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart())) {
            String element = e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
            // Then run through events until a closing similar element
            do {
                e = super.nextEvent();
            } while (e.getEventType() != XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT || !element.equals(e.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart()));
            // then read next tag after closing element
            e = super.nextEvent();
        }
        return e;
    }
}
```

Then unmarshall your content using this `XMLEventReader`:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
XMLEventReader xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml));
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FilteredXmlEventReader(xmlReader, "Dog", "Bird"));
```

Then `Dog` and `Birds` elements will not be read.

Note that there can be issues if multiple filtered elements are nested with this implementation.

**EDIT: Edited the code above to support multiple filtered elements.**

Comment: First of all, thank you for response. I read about XMLEvent, and it looks like a quite nice idea for filtering.
But what if I had Dogs, Cats and Birds, and I would like to read only cats? To filter all classes except Cats?
if (e.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && ("Dog".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()) ||
          "Bird".equals(e.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart())) 

Is not working. If I try different ways, and I cannot come up with idea how to change that code.

Comment: The `FilterDogXmlEventReader` i wrote in the answer is dummy. You may improve it by adding an instance variable containing all filtered values. You would then set the filtered values when constructing the event reader.  Then iterating on all filtered values instead of matching only `Dog`

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i wanted to achieve. I need to read carefully how you done that, to understand it more, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since in the Root class animals is taking both dog and cat as elements it would try to marshal it to both of those objects if available.

One way to achieve what you want is remove one of the element under XmlElementWrapper.

```
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "animals")
  @XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "cat", type = Cat.class)
  })
  public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }
```

The above would give you:

```
Root{animals=[ com.memorynotfound.xml.jaxb.Cat@18eed359]}
```

Comment: But in that Case I will be unable to read Dogs. I want to read the objects from the chosen class, so only the Cats, (Or the dogs, if the user will chose the dog class).
Using your solution i will be able to read only the cats, that is true. But if the user will change his mind, i will not be able to read only the dogs.